# How to wait for a response from the server

Tags: android, kotlin, request, retrofit

In my android mobile app, I access my server with a *POST* request using *retrofit* to get a token in the response body for user authorization. I need to wait for a response from the server for further work in the application.
How can I do this?

If I call the enqueue() method, I immediately get a null error

But the execute() method doesn't work(I don't get any response)

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val api = ApiInterface.create()
    fun fetch() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val data = api.post()
                Log.d("Log", "${data.execute().body()?.userId}")
            }
            catch (e: Exception){}
        }
    }
}
```

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/posts/add")
    suspend fun post() : Call<gett>

    companion object {
        var BASE_URL = "https://dummyjson.com"

        fun create() : ApiInterface {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

My data class

```
data class gett(
    val title: String,
    val userId: Int
)
```

Please tell me how I can wait for a response from the server

Comment: Are you literally trying to post to `https://dummyjson.com/posts/add`? That seems wrong. Explain what "dosn't work" means - are there errors? Is it a success response with no data?

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to define a suspend function that returns a Call. Make it just return `gett` directly. And you should name your classes starting with a capital letter or your code will be very hard to read.

Comment: using handler and progressbar i guess